# Show an animated progressbar GIF image in android

Tags: android

I have a Splash Screen for an Android Project in which I have to add a progress bar for 5 seconds but the problem is that the screen's background is white and our progress bar doesn't displayed on that, due to this reason I downloaded a progress bar GIF image which is not animating in Android, So the question is that How am I able to animating GIF progress bar file on my Splash Screen.

Please suggest me the right solution regarding the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use black progress bar style which is inbuilt:

```
<ProgressBar style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"/>
```

Also if you want to use your animated image: you can refer [here](http://www.hrupin.com/2011/09/how-to-make-custom-indeterminate-progressbar-in-android-or-how-to-change-progressbar-style-or-color)